# How to list all test names which were executed during `bazel test` command - even passing ones

Tags: bazel

only failed tests are displayed at the end of bazel test command.
what bazel flag can help in listing passing tests as well?
Adding `--test_summary=detailed` lists all passing subtests which again is lot of output. Looking to print only test names with status.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`--test_summary=short` prints the name of every test target and its status at the end of the Bazel invocation. `short` is the default value of `--test_summary`, though, so maybe you're expecting something else?